# WPF - ListBox ignores Style When ItemsSource is bound

Tags: wpf, xaml, styling, listboxitem, staticresource

I have created styled a ListBox in WPF so that it is rendered as a checkbox list.

When I populate the ListBox's items manually, the styling works perfectly. However, when I instead bind the ItemsSource of the ListBox to a static resource (an ItemsControl containing the required items), the styling is completely dropped.

Here's the style:

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxListStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Grid Margin="2">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <ContentPresenter
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Margin="2,0,0,0" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"  />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
</Style>
```

Here's the code for the ListBox that shows the style correctly:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ColumnsList"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxListStyle}"
            BorderThickness="1">                                                
            <ListBox.Items>
                <ListBoxItem>Test</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Test2</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Test3</ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox.Items>
        </ListBox>
```

Here's the code for the ListBox that ignores the style:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ColumnsList2"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxListStyle}"
            BorderThickness="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Test1}, Path=Items}">
        </ListBox>
```

Hoping someone can help - I'm pretty new to all this and have tried everything I can think of, but everything I've read leads me to believe that setting ItemsSource should have the same outcome as setting the items manually, so I can't see any reason why this would not work.

Thanks,

AT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the Style.Resources to setting the `ItemContainerStyle` property and it should work like a charm.

```
    <Style x:Key="CheckBoxListStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Grid Margin="2">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                <ContentPresenter
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Margin="2,0,0,0" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"  />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
</Style>
```

In older versions (before SP1), when you define `Style`s in Style, one of those style will be ignored. Alternatively, you can set the Resources of Style in the parent resources..

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great - except you forget the Setter.Value tag. Apart from that, it seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is because your TargetType in the CheckListBoxStyle is targetting a ListBoxItem, but when you set the ItemSource property of the ListBox you are binding to a list of other elements (ints for example).  This means your target type should be int instead of ListBoxItem.

Alternatively do not specify a target type.